# How is showAlertViewForRequestOperationWithErrorOnCompletion supposed to be used?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am uncertain how `showAlertViewForRequestOperationWithErrorOnCompletion` from the new AFNetworking is supposed to be used. I tried the following, but no alertView is shown.

```
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id requestObject) {
    // ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [UIAlertView showAlertViewForRequestOperationWithErrorOnCompletion:operation
                                                              delegate:nil];
}];
```

Comment: I was able to google this. I am sure you have already seen it. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIAlertView%2BAFNetworking.m

Comment: I found the code yes, but as a beginner it was not clear to me how the created block and the notification play together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you sure that that line of code is being reached?
2. An alert is only shown if the error of the operation is non-nil. Are you sure this is the case?

**Update:**

Ok, so it looks like by the [implementation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIAlertView+AFNetworking.m) that calling this doesn't show the alert right away, but just sets it up so that when the operation fails, an alert is showed. So you'd have to probably do:

```
[UIAlertView showAlertViewForRequestOperationWithErrorOnCompletion:requestOperation
                                                              delegate:nil];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id requestObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: 2. Yes, the error is non-nil, domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: -1000.

Comment: Correct, you were right. I have to say the API is a bit counter intuitive. A better name would be "onCompletionWithErrorShowAlertViewForRequestOperation:requestOperation delegate:nil" (and it should be called from within the failure block).

Comment: Ok, now comparing to APIs like `showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:task` is seems reasonable.